# How to make a star rating default 5 and change after selected

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Here by default it will 0. but i want by default 5 star selected and then i should be able to change.
i tried to make rateValue = 5 but didn't work. Can anyone help?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
  /* 1. Visualizing things on Hover - See next part for action on click */
  $('#stars li').on('mouseover', function(){
    var onStar = parseInt($(this).data('value'), 10); // The star currently mouse on
   
    // Now highlight all the stars that's not after the current hovered star
    $(this).parent().children('li.star').each(function(e){
      if (e < onStar) {
        $(this).addClass('hover');
      }
      else {
        $(this).removeClass('hover');
      }
    });
    
  }).on('mouseout', function(){
    $(this).parent().children('li.star').each(function(e){
      $(this).removeClass('hover');
    });
  });
  
  
  /* 2. Action to perform on click */
  $('#stars li').on('click', function(){
    var onStar = parseInt($(this).data('value'), 10); // The star currently selected
    var stars = $(this).parent().children('li.star');
    
    for (i = 0; i < stars.length; i++) {
      $(stars[i]).removeClass('selected');
    }
    
    for (i = 0; i < onStar; i++) {
      $(stars[i]).addClass('selected');
    }
    
    // JUST RESPONSE (Not needed)
    var ratingValue = parseInt($('#stars li.selected').last().data('value'), 10);
    var msg = "";
    if (ratingValue > 1) {
        msg = "Thanks! You rated this " + ratingValue + " stars.";
    }
    else {
        msg = "We will improve ourselves. You rated this " + ratingValue + " stars.";
    }
    responseMessage(msg);
    
  });
  
  
});


function responseMessage(msg) {
  $('.success-box').fadeIn(200);  
  $('.success-box div.text-message').html("<span>" + msg + "</span>");
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family:"Open Sans", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  color:#555;
  max-width:680px;
  margin:0 auto;
  padding:0 20px;
}

* {
  -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

*:before, *:after {
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
}

.clearfix {
  clear:both;
}

.text-center {text-align:center;}

a {
  color: tomato;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
  color: #2196f3;
}

pre {
display: block;
padding: 9.5px;
margin: 0 0 10px;
font-size: 13px;
line-height: 1.42857143;
color: #333;
word-break: break-all;
word-wrap: break-word;
background-color: #F5F5F5;
border: 1px solid #CCC;
border-radius: 4px;
}

.header {
  padding:20px 0;
  position:relative;
  margin-bottom:10px;
  
}

.header:after {
  content:"";
  display:block;
  height:1px;
  background:#eee;
  position:absolute; 
  left:30%; right:30%;
}

.header h2 {
  font-size:3em;
  font-weight:300;
  margin-bottom:0.2em;
}

.header p {
  font-size:14px;
}



#a-footer {
  margin: 20px 0;
}

.new-react-version {
  padding: 20px 20px;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  border-radius: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 12px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
  
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.7;
}

.new-react-version .react-svg-logo {
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 60px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  margin-top: 0;
}





.success-box {
  margin:50px 0;
  padding:10px 10px;
  border:1px solid #eee;
  background:#f9f9f9;
}

.success-box img {
  margin-right:10px;
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
}

.success-box > div {
  vertical-align:top;
  display:inline-block;
  color:#888;
}



/* Rating Star Widgets Style */
.rating-stars ul {
  list-style-type:none;
  padding:0;
  
  -moz-user-select:none;
  -webkit-user-select:none;
}
.rating-stars ul > li.star {
  display:inline-block;
  
}

/* Idle State of the stars */
.rating-stars ul > li.star > i.fa {
  font-size:2.5em; /* Change the size of the stars */
  color:#ccc; /* Color on idle state */
}

/* Hover state of the stars */
.rating-stars ul > li.star.hover > i.fa {
  color:#FFCC36;
}

/* Selected state of the stars */
.rating-stars ul > li.star.selected > i.fa {
  color:#FF912C;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />

<header class='header text-center'>
    <h2>Rating Widget</h2>
  <p>A simple star rating widget with <b>jQuery</b> and <b>FontAwesome</b> icons.</p>
</header>

<section class='rating-widget'>
  
  <!-- Rating Stars Box -->
  <div class='rating-stars text-center'>
    <ul id='stars'>
      <li class='star' title='Poor' data-value='1'>
        <i class='fa fa-star fa-fw'></i>
      </li>
      <li class='star' title='Fair' data-value='2'>
        <i class='fa fa-star fa-fw'></i>
      </li>
      <li class='star' title='Good' data-value='3'>
        <i class='fa fa-star fa-fw'></i>
      </li>
      <li class='star' title='Excellent' data-value='4'>
        <i class='fa fa-star fa-fw'></i>
      </li>
      <li class='star' title='WOW!!!' data-value='5'>
        <i class='fa fa-star fa-fw'></i>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  
  <div class='success-box'>
    <div class='clearfix'></div>
    <img alt='tick image' width='32' src='data:image/svg+xml;utf8;base64,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'/>
    <div class='text-message'></div>
    <div class='clearfix'></div>
  </div>
  
  
  
</section>
```

Initially it should be 5 stars by default. later based on Change it should changed. I'm new to jQuery.i also tried to remove selected class but thats not working.

Comment: Simply on load add this `$('#stars li.star').addClass('selected')` that should work .

Comment: Just add this `$('#stars [data-value="5"]').trigger('click')`

Answer (score 2):

You can just add the class in HTML as it gets reomved / added anyway by your JQuery

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
  /* 1. Visualizing things on Hover - See next part for action on click */
  $('#stars li').on('mouseover', function(){
    var onStar = parseInt($(this).data('value'), 10); // The star currently mouse on
   
    // Now highlight all the stars that's not after the current hovered star
    $(this).parent().children('li.star').each(function(e){
      if (e < onStar) {
        $(this).addClass('hover');
      }
      else {
        $(this).removeClass('hover');
      }
    });
    
  }).on('mouseout', function(){
    $(this).parent().children('li.star').each(function(e){
      $(this).removeClass('hover');
    });
  });
  
  
  /* 2. Action to perform on click */
  $('#stars li').on('click', function(){
    var onStar = parseInt($(this).data('value'), 10); // The star currently selected
    var stars = $(this).parent().children('li.star');
    
    for (i = 0; i < stars.length; i++) {
      $(stars[i]).removeClass('selected');
    }
    
    for (i = 0; i < onStar; i++) {
      $(stars[i]).addClass('selected');
    }
    
    // JUST RESPONSE (Not needed)
    var ratingValue = parseInt($('#stars li.selected').last().data('value'), 10);
    var msg = "";
    if (ratingValue > 1) {
        msg = "Thanks! You rated this " + ratingValue + " stars.";
    }
    else {
        msg = "We will improve ourselves. You rated this " + ratingValue + " stars.";
    }
    responseMessage(msg);
    
  });
  
  
});


function responseMessage(msg) {
  $('.success-box').fadeIn(200);  
  $('.success-box div.text-message').html("<span>" + msg + "</span>");
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family:"Open Sans", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  color:#555;
  max-width:680px;
  margin:0 auto;
  padding:0 20px;
}

* {
  -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

*:before, *:after {
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
}

.clearfix {
  clear:both;
}

.text-center {text-align:center;}

a {
  color: tomato;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
  color: #2196f3;
}

pre {
display: block;
padding: 9.5px;
margin: 0 0 10px;
font-size: 13px;
line-height: 1.42857143;
color: #333;
word-break: break-all;
word-wrap: break-word;
background-color: #F5F5F5;
border: 1px solid #CCC;
border-radius: 4px;
}

.header {
  padding:20px 0;
  position:relative;
  margin-bottom:10px;
  
}

.header:after {
  content:"";
  display:block;
  height:1px;
  background:#eee;
  position:absolute; 
  left:30%; right:30%;
}

.header h2 {
  font-size:3em;
  font-weight:300;
  margin-bottom:0.2em;
}

.header p {
  font-size:14px;
}



#a-footer {
  margin: 20px 0;
}

.new-react-version {
  padding: 20px 20px;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  border-radius: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 12px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
  
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.7;
}

.new-react-version .react-svg-logo {
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 60px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  margin-top: 0;
}





.success-box {
  margin:50px 0;
  padding:10px 10px;
  border:1px solid #eee;
  background:#f9f9f9;
}

.success-box img {
  margin-right:10px;
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
}

.success-box > div {
  vertical-align:top;
  display:inline-block;
  color:#888;
}



/* Rating Star Widgets Style */
.rating-stars ul {
  list-style-type:none;
  padding:0;
  
  -moz-user-select:none;
  -webkit-user-select:none;
}
.rating-stars ul > li.star {
  display:inline-block;
  
}

/* Idle State of the stars */
.rating-stars ul > li.star > i.fa {
  font-size:2.5em; /* Change the size of the stars */
  color:#ccc; /* Color on idle state */
}

/* Hover state of the stars */
.rating-stars ul > li.star.hover > i.fa {
  color:#FFCC36;
}

/* Selected state of the stars */
.rating-stars ul > li.star.selected > i.fa {
  color:#FF912C;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />

<header class='header text-center'>
    <h2>Rating Widget</h2>
  <p>A simple star rating widget with <b>jQuery</b> and <b>FontAwesome</b> icons.</p>
</header>

<section class='rating-widget'>
  
  <!-- Rating Stars Box -->
  <div class='rating-stars text-center'>
    <ul id='stars'>
      <li class='star selected' title='Poor' data-value='1'>
        <i class='fa fa-star fa-fw'></i>
      </li>
      <li class='star selected' title='Fair' data-value='2'>
        <i class='fa fa-star fa-fw'></i>
      </li>
      <li class='star selected' title='Good' data-value='3'>
        <i class='fa fa-star fa-fw'></i>
      </li>
      <li class='star selected' title='Excellent' data-value='4'>
        <i class='fa fa-star fa-fw'></i>
      </li>
      <li class='star selected' title='WOW!!!' data-value='5'>
        <i class='fa fa-star fa-fw'></i>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  
  <div class='success-box'>
    <div class='clearfix'></div>
    <img alt='tick image' width='32' src='data:image/svg+xml;utf8;base64,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'/>
    <div class='text-message'></div>
    <div class='clearfix'></div>
  </div>
  
  
  
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add the `selected` class on `<li>` By default in HTML.

```
<ul id='stars'>
      <li class='star selected' title='Poor' data-value='1'>
        <i class='fa fa-star fa-fw'></i>
      </li>
      <li class='star selected' title='Fair' data-value='2'>
        <i class='fa fa-star fa-fw'></i>
      </li>
      <li class='star selected' title='Good' data-value='3'>
        <i class='fa fa-star fa-fw'></i>
      </li>
      <li class='star selected' title='Excellent' data-value='4'>
        <i class='fa fa-star fa-fw'></i>
      </li>
      <li class='star selected' title='WOW!!!' data-value='5'>
        <i class='fa fa-star fa-fw'></i>
      </li>
    </ul>
```